# exception handling and (throw ex)

Tags: exception

What is the best way to handle an exception?
Also, why should I never write:

```
catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
```

Comment: You might want to specify in which language this is in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle an exception is to do something meaningful in the `catch` block (the one which in your example contains `throw ex`). The definition of "meaningful" completely depends on your needs.

You should not do `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` because that brakes the exception chain. It is perfectly fine to catch an exception, handle it and re-throw so that the calling code can see it, but you should be doing so like this:

```
catch (Exception ex) { /* handling code; */ throw; }
```

Comment: This works fine in C++, but doesn't in, for example, Java.  Which is why the original poster *really* needs to identify the language he's asking about.

Comment: @JUST In fact, I assumed C# by default ;) Considering the other OP's questions, it might even be a good assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you catch the expection to just throw it again, if you were to catch the exception and do something other than just throw it, it would be fine!

```
try 
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 // do something like log the exception
 throw ex; // let another catch block handle the expection.
}
```